# Como hacer un form para verificar si es administrador?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Trabajo con vb.net, tengo un form donde hace una consulta a mysql y revisa si tiene permisos de administrador si es así ejecuta la función, pero es muy sencillo, por decirse asi, quisiera que fuera general, si el validador regresa cierto valor entonces si procede

Esto esto que he hecho hasta ahora

```
Private Sub Validar()
        Dim rd As MySqlDataReader
        Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection With {
            .ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MySQL").ConnectionString
        }

        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "SELECT root FROM usuarios WHERE login=@u AND passwd=@p"
            Dim command = New MySqlCommand(query, con)

            command.Parameters.Add("@u", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtUser.Text
            command.Parameters.Add("@p", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtPass.Text

            rd = command.ExecuteReader()
            If rd.Read() Then
                If rd("root") = "1" Then
                    Dim l As New TCRegistro
                    MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "U ar Root", "Information!",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    With l
                        .InsertarDatos()
                    End With
                    Me.Close()
                Else
                    MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "You do not have sufficient privileges", "Information!",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                End If
            End If
        Catch

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try

// AQUI EL CODIGO ES MUY SENCILLO 

If My.User.IsInRole(ApplicationServices.BuiltInRole.Administrator) Then  

con.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "SELECT root FROM usuarios WHERE login=@u AND passwd=@p"
        Dim command = New MySqlCommand(query, con)

    command.Parameters.Add("@u", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtUser.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@p", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtPass.Text

    rd = command.ExecuteReader()
    If rd.Read() Then
        If rd("root") = "1" Then
            Dim l As New TCRegistro
            MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "U ar Root", "Information!",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            With l
                .InsertarDatos()
            End With
            Me.Close()
        Else
            MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "You do not have sufficient privileges", "Information!",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
//ACA LE PUEDES CERRA LA APP CON LA FUNCION ME.CLOSE SI NO CUMPLE CON LA FUNCION 
            End If
        End If
    Catch

    End Try
End Sub
```